# Swift 5, How do I get notifications from the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I had seen other people get the method .userInfo in swift 4.2 from the NotificationCenter... My question is how do I find The userInfo in swift 5.2... it tells me when i get this far

```
  @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NotificationCenter) {
if let keyboardsize = (notification.userInfo?)
}
```

That .userInfo? Isnt a method of NotificationCenter... So how can I make my view adjust to the keyboard if I cant get info like height off of the keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I am assuming you are listening to keyboard notification events, i.e. `Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow`

second, it is not of type `NotificationCenter` it is of type `Notification`

to get the specific Keyboard frame you can use the `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserINfoKey`

more info on this enum [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621578-keyboardframeenduserinfokey)

example on how to get the frame inside a Notification's userInfo

```swift
  @objc
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardFrame = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
             let keyboardFrame = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
              //print keyboardFrame.height
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes I had ended up realizing the reason Notification didnt work when I initially tried it was because my xcode beta crashed so that led me to using NotificationCenter which you now clarified was wrong... Thank you for the help!  Also just so you know... In Swift 5 with Xcode 11.5 instead of UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey its actually UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey